# Size of verticalLayout is different in Qt Designer and PyQt program

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

In Qt Designer 5.9 the `verticalLayout` in `test.ui` had a certain distance to the edge of the window, but after loading `test.ui` with PyQt 5.11.3 in `main.py` the `verticalLayout` extend to the edge of the window.

**main.py**:

```
    #!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        loadUi("test.ui", self)

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow(app)
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
main()
```

**test.ui**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>350</width>
    <height>257</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Test</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_2">
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
      <property name="leftMargin">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <property name="topMargin">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <item>
       <spacer name="verticalSpacer_2">
        <property name="orientation">
         <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
         <size>
          <width>20</width>
          <height>40</height>
         </size>
        </property>
       </spacer>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox">
        <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
         <item row="1" column="1">
          <widget class="QSpinBox" name="spinBox">
           <property name="maximum">
            <number>100000</number>
           </property>
           <property name="value">
            <number>1000</number>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item row="1" column="0">
          <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
           <property name="text">
            <string>Test</string>
           </property>
           <property name="alignment">
            <set>Qt::AlignRight|Qt::AlignTrailing|Qt::AlignVCenter</set>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item row="0" column="1">
          <widget class="QComboBox" name="comboBox">
           <property name="currentText">
            <string/>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item row="0" column="0">
          <widget class="QLabel" name="label1">
           <property name="text">
            <string>Test</string>
           </property>
           <property name="alignment">
            <set>Qt::AlignRight|Qt::AlignTrailing|Qt::AlignVCenter</set>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
        </layout>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <spacer name="verticalSpacer">
        <property name="orientation">
         <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
         <size>
          <width>20</width>
          <height>40</height>
         </size>
        </property>
       </spacer>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
        <property name="layoutDirection">
         <enum>Qt::LeftToRight</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Test</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>350</width>
     <height>28</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

---

Screenshot of `test.ui` in Qt Designer 5.9:

[image]

Screenshot of `main.py` loading `test.ui`:

[image]

What's the reason for this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the code of `uic.loadUi()` you will find the following code:

**uiparser.py**

```
class UIParser(object):  
    # ...
    def createLayout(self, elem):
        # ...
        margin = -1 if self.stack.topIsLayout() else self.defaults['margin']
        margin = self.wprops.getProperty(elem, 'margin', margin)
        left = self.wprops.getProperty(elem, 'leftMargin', margin)
        top = self.wprops.getProperty(elem, 'topMargin', margin)
        right = self.wprops.getProperty(elem, 'rightMargin', margin)
        bottom = self.wprops.getProperty(elem, 'bottomMargin', margin)
        # A layout widget should, by default, have no margins.
        if self.stack.topIsLayoutWidget():
            if left < 0: left = 0
            if top < 0: top = 0
            if right < 0: right = 0
            if bottom < 0: bottom = 0

    def topIsLayoutWidget(self):
        # A plain QWidget is a layout widget unless it's parent is a
        # QMainWindow or a container widget.  Note that the corresponding uic
        # test is a little more complicated as it involves features not
        # supported by pyuic.

        if type(self[-1]) is not QtWidgets.QWidget:
            return False

        if len(self) < 2:
            return False

        parent = self[-2]

        return isinstance(parent, QtWidgets.QWidget) and type(parent) not in (
                QtWidgets.QMainWindow,
                QtWidgets.QStackedWidget,
                QtWidgets.QToolBox,
                QtWidgets.QTabWidget,
                QtWidgets.QScrollArea,
                QtWidgets.QMdiArea,
                QtWidgets.QWizard,
                QtWidgets.QDockWidget)
```

The problem is caused by the `topIsLayoutWidget()` function since the parent will refer to the widget that is used as a base, in this case MainWindow complies with `isinstance(parent, QtWidgets.QWidget) and type (parent) not in (QtWidgets.QMainWindow, ...)` so `topIsLayoutWidget()` will return True, so to be left, top, right, bottom be -1 since those properties do not exist will be updated to 0 so the apply to `contentsMargins` will be established by eliminating the default value (9, 9, 9, 9), but in the case of Qt Designer the `contentsMargins` have not been updated maintaining their default value.

So in conclusion is a pyqt bug that also points in the comments:

```
# ... Note that the corresponding uic
# test is a little more complicated as it involves features not
# supported by pyuic.*
```

So there are several solutions:

- Remove:

  ```
  if self.stack.topIsLayoutWidget():
      if left < 0: left = 0
      if top < 0: top = 0
      if right < 0: right = 0
      if bottom < 0: bottom = 0
  ```
- Use `uic.loadUiType()`:

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/python3
  import sys
  from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, uic

  Ui_Interface, _ = uic.loadUiType('test.ui')

  class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Interface):
      def __init__(self, parent=None):
          super().__init__(parent)
          self.setupUi(self)

  def main():
      app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
      main_window = MainWindow()
      main_window.show()
      sys.exit(app.exec_())

  if __name__ == "__main__":
      main()
  ```

I prefer the second solution since the source code should not be modified.

Comment: @ eyllanesc sorry, isn't it easier to convert test.ui to test_ui.py?

Comment: @S.Nick It is also a valid option, but according to what the OP points out, I think he wants to keep the .ui, so for me the proper solution is to use loadUiType: you do not need to convert to .py and it does not generate the problem of margins.

Comment: @eyllanesc: Thank you for your detailed answer and suggested solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Based off @eyllanesc's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53470499/13831226), here's a [monkey patch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) that fixed the issue for me.

This solution works because the only code inside PyQt5 that cares about the `WidgetStack.topIsLayoutWidget` attribute is the `UIParser.createLayout()` method, and it only uses that attribute to decide whether to set the default margins to zero.

```py
from PyQt5.uic import uiparser

uiparser.WidgetStack.topIsLayoutWidget = lambda self: False
```