# Loading MainWindow Qt Creator .ui design into QMainWindow subclass with PyQt6 results in different appearance

Tags: python, qt

Loading an UI design from Qt Creator:

[image: loaded]

and attempting to load and subclass the .ui file a results in a "borderless" window:

[image: subclassed]

What is happening when subclassing it?
I'd like it so both appear the same, i.e. loading the UI into the subclass should appear like the UI loaded directly (and as in Qt Creator GUI preview).

mainwindow.ui :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>535</width>
    <height>362</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
    <item>
     <widget class="QGraphicsView" name="graphicsView"/>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
      <property name="text">
       <string>PushButton</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QProgressBar" name="progressBar">
      <property name="value">
       <number>24</number>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Python:

```
import sys
from PyQt6 import QtWidgets, uic

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.ui = uic.loadUi("mainwindow.ui", self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle("MainWindow()")
    # window = uic.loadUi("mainwindow.ui")
    # window.setWindowTitle("MainWindow.ui")
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: @musicamante That's it - the Qt Creator preview shows it properly too. Explanation and fix from the Q&A referred as duplicate, https://stackoverflow.com/a/62629256: `uic.uiparser.WidgetStack.topIsLayoutWidget = lambda self: False`